# When Using Fabric To Add Image, Why Does All Images Gets Replaced By New One?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have some code that, when you type into a textbox, it converts the text into an image and adds it to a canvas using the FabricJS library.

CodeSandBox Live Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sjskdh-eomxtz?file=/src/App.js

Main Snippet:

```
  async function SampleAction() {
    console.clear();
    //const html = description.htmlValue;
    const htmlDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
      description.htmlValue,
      "text/html"
    );
    htmlDOM.firstChild.setAttribute("style", "padding: 0; margin:0");
    //const html = htmlDOM.documentElement.innerHTML;

    /* HTML is printing below*/
    const invisibleDiv = document.createElement("div");
    invisibleDiv.setAttribute("id", "invisibleDiv");
    invisibleDiv.setAttribute(
      "style",
      "display: inline-block; background-color: transparent; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
    );

    invisibleDiv.innerHTML = htmlDOM.documentElement.innerHTML;
    hiddenDiv.current.appendChild(invisibleDiv);
    const htmlDomImg = await html2canvas(invisibleDiv, {
      backgroundColor: null
    });
    imgRef.current.src = "";
    imgRef.current.src = htmlDomImg.toDataURL();
    imgRef.current.style.height = htmlDomImg.style.height;
    imgRef.current.style.width = htmlDomImg.style.width;

    const newItm = new fabric.Image(imgRef.current, {
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: imgRef.current.width,
      height: imgRef.current.height,
      id: (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7),
      objectDNA: {
        type: "text",
        text: htmlDOM.querySelector("html").textContent,
        rawHTML: htmlDOM.firstChild
      }
    });

    invisibleDiv.remove();

    setImgLayers([...imgLayers, newItm]);
  }
```

What I expect is that, when I add a new object, all other objects are not affected. What happens though is that all the images get replaced. This is a GIF here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkA7W.jpg [*Sorry, StackOverFlow doesnt allow me to post GIFs*]

I checked the objects and they look different, other than the img.
[image]
[image]

What is the issue?

Comment: You seems to be creating a new canvas each time. Also we need to see the rest of the code. the setImgLayers function seems to be handling it.

Comment: @Lk77 the rest of the code is in the CodeSandbox